change shell script execution time (unknown task scheduler)
Kind of an embarrassing question to ask.
I have a server which runs under Debian 10.
It has 2 users: root and another one that I use for the application on the server.
There is a bash script that runs everyday under root. I need to change the time it runs.
I point out that it is a self made script that is located in the home directory of the application user.
Theres is nothing in root crontab or the user crontab. There is nothing in /etc/cron.daily or /etc/cron.d.
The list from systemctl list-timers:

systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
logrotate.service
man-db.service
apt-daily.service
apt-daily-upgrade.service

Is there anybody that have an idea how it might be implemented ?

@waltinator here is the output of journalctl:
juil. 08 03:30:01 vps-xxxx.xxxx.fr CRON[32373]: (root) CMD (   test -e /home/ibis/sauvegardeApplicatif/sh/sauvegarde.sh && /home/ibis/sauvegardeApplicatif/sh/sauvegarde.sh

It seems to be run by root crontab but nothing in root crontab . It is empty.

@aviro  the output of
sxsudo grep -Isr sauvegarde.sh /etc/cron*

/etc/crontab:30 3    * * *   root    test -e /home/ibis/sauvegardeApplicatif/sh/sauvegarde.sh && /home/ibis/sauvegardeApplicatif/sh/sauvegarde.sh -gz

Thanks to you and everyone who helped me

does systemctl list-timers (with or without --user) show anything?

(I mean, run systemctl list-timers as root, and systemctl --user list-timers as that other user)

I presume systemctl --user list-timers executed as that other user yielded nothing?

what other things does the server do? I remember the horrible days of PHP (it's probably still like that for most PHP software, I just came to the conclusion that if it's written in PHP, I won't run it) where, absent of many choices or the ability to research how to do things correctly, developers needed to simply check, for every single time a webserver executed any part of a PHP web application, whether it was time to run a task. With hilarious if predictably bad results if the application was not called, or the webserver was set up for multi-process workers.

result of systemctl --user --all list-timers =>  0 timers listed. the server has a web site and the script makes a tar of the database files

Then really check the scripts that the web server executes, if any, for the name of the script (grep -Ri is your friend).

And you don't remember how you set up this script in the first place? Are you sure it's being executed by root? Did you check /etc/crontab? If you can modify the script you're running, you can add the following line there: pstree -sap $$ >> /tmp/myscript.log. That way you'll see the process tree of your script, including the parent, and you can find who or what executed it in the first place. You can [edit] your question and add the output of this file once you see the process tree.

Check /var/spool/cron/crontabs/.  Use journalctl's --since and --before options (man journalctl) to look at the logs at the job start time to see how it's started.

Possibly it's running with at? Try at -l as root and the app user.

I don't think there's a need to add pstree now, we already see in your journal that your script was executed by a cron. Run the following command instead: grep -Isr sauvegarde.sh /etc/cron* /var/spool/cron/tabs/

The cron job could be located in the directory /etc/cron.d

It's in /etc/crontab.
